# Why Callback not working with mongoose findOne method?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Using Expressjs and mongoose in a node application. I am trying to implement passportjs authentication. **When I call the new LocalStrategy and passing the username and a callback function to get the username if exist, the callback function is not executing.** To verify the I printed a console message is callback but even message is not showing. Why this is happening and how I can resolve it?

This is the router( index.js)

```js
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Login POst called")
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: 'true'
  })(req, res, next);
}); 

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  (username, password, done)=>{
    console.log("Local Strategy called")
    User.getUserByUsername(username, (err, user)=>{
      console.log("this message should display in callback"); // this message is not displaying
      if(err) throw err;
      if(!user){
        return done(null, false, {message: "No user found"});
    }

    User.comparePassword(password, user.password, (err, isMatch)=>{
      if(err) throw err;
      if(isMatch){
         return done(null, user);
      }
      else{
        return done(null, false, {message: "Wrong Password"});
      }
    });
  });
  }
));
```

this is the model (User.js)

```js
module.exports.getUserByUsername = (username, callback)=>{
    console.log("GetUsername called")
    const query = { username: username }
    console.log(query);
    User.findOne(query).exec(callback);
}

module.exports.getUserById = (id, callback)=>{
    console.log("GetId called")
    User.findId(id).exec(callback);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to return in `getUserByUsername`

Comment: @Ashish can you please show me how you to return correct output. I am not able to find it.

Comment: `return User.findOne(query).exec();`  here